# Use Spring Security with JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring.

We are using spring security feature.
Database connectivity: eclipselink implementation of JPA.
Database: MySql

While using spring security, Configuration of  authentication provider is as follows,-

```
<authentication-provider>

    <jdbc-user-service id="userDetailsService" data-source-ref="Datasource" />

    </authentication-provider>
```

But in JPA we do not define datasource, we use Persistence unit with provider `jpa.PersistenceProvider.`

So how do we configure authentication provider so as to use JPA for database connectivity?

What exactly should data-source-ref field contain to use database for authentication?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically you probably need to [implement `UserDetailsService` yourself](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1588).

So you would for example have a `User` entity, and your [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) implementation would look up the user and convert it to a [`UserDetails`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/index.html) object (or your entity would have to implement `UserDetails`).

**Sample implementation:**

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager newEm){
        this.entityManager = newEm;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){

        // assuming that you have a User class that implements UserDetails
        return entityManager.createQuery("from User where username = :username", User.class)
                            .setParameter("username", username)
                            .getSingleResult();

    }
}
```

And you add this to user `spring-security.xml`

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="MyUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Your custom UserDetailsService would use JPA, (and your DB schema) to create the UserDetails object.

Comment: Well yes, I thought that was rather obvious :-)

Comment: I did of course mean UserDetailsService, not AuthenticationUserDetailsService

Comment: hi, thanks for responce, But how do I customise userdetail service. any reference code will help. thank u all

Comment: @Sean Patrick  Floyd: Can you suggest any tutorial or useful link for "Spring security with jpa" Or can you show 'how implemented methods of userDetails class look in User class?'

Answer (score 11):

An easier way for authentication in your case is to get one of your service layer classes implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` interface. This interface contain only one method `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)`. You have to make sure that you return a `UserDetails` instance for a given username.

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    // load and return user using your regular JPA techniques here
        ...
    }
```

Once you have implemented this method in your service class, you will simply need to add its reference your spring configuration file:

```
<authentication-manager>
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myServiceLayerClassInstance">
     </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: This is the best answer - IMO