# Can Spring Security 3.1 use EclipseLink persistence unit?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm using Spring Security 3.1 with Spring 3.2 and with EclipseLink JPA. I'm configuring Spring Security to use users and groups from a MySQL database. All the Spring documentation and tutorials says to use

```
<authentication-provider> 
  <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" /> 
</authentication-provider> 

<bean id = "dataSource" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
  <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
  <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webcosts"/> 
  <property name = "username" value = "root"/> 
  <property name = "password" value = "root"/> 
</bean>
```

However I've already defined my data source in persistence.xml similar to below

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

etc

Is there any way to have the jdbc-user-service reference the persistence-unit directly or perhaps via an adapter, or do I need to enter my database information twice and have two sets of database connections?

I've done a google search, and I've read the Spring documentation, but I can't find much. Spring documentation seems to be written by experts, for experts, it's not entirely intuitive for beginners to the framework!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489703/how-to-use-spring-security-with-jpa