# Spring Security to user JPA connection

Tags: jsf, jpa, spring-security

I tried to follow this post from StackOverflow ([Use Spring Security with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489703/how-to-use-spring-security-with-jpa)) without success.

I implemented an UserDetailsService:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.boss.mrfoods.dao.UserDao;
import com.boss.mrfoods.entity.User;

@Service
public class LoginController implements UserDetailsService {

    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        User user = userDao.getForUsername(username);

        System.out.println("USERNAME: " + username);
        System.out.println("USER: " + user);
        System.out.println("ROLES:" + user.getRoles());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getRoles());
    }

}
```

And referenced it in one of the Spring XML Configuration files like this:

```
<debug />

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/pages/loggedout.xhtml" security="none" />
<http pattern="/pages/timeout.xhtml" security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/**" access="hasRole('supervisor')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/user/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login />
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/loggedout.xhtml" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <remember-me />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.boss.mrfoods.controller.LoginController" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Nothing happens. No exceptions and my UserDetailsService implementation is never called.

What I am trying to archieve is to Spring Security use my JPA connection/transaction to find the users/roles. Am I missing configs? Where do I start looking for problems if I'm not even getting and exception.

**What I have found out this far is: my userDao is null. The object injection does not work. Inject is not being able to build the object. Why?**

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: how are you attempting to authenticate? Do you have an `http` element in your security config?

Comment: edited the question to show more of the XML config file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on how you logged-in to the application. Are you visiting the user pages directly and expecting a login page ?

Have you tried setting up your login page like this ,

```
 <form-login
        login-page="/login.html"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.action"
        authentication-failure-url="/login_error.html"
        default-target-url="/home.html"
        always-use-default-target="true"/>
```

Comment: I'm using the default login form (you can realize that by the line "<form-login />" in my XML.).
The form is correctly shown when trying to access one of the secured pages, but when I try to log in, I do not get authenticated and my breakpoints and sysouts are never called.

Comment: Can you give more details about what is happening when you are logging in . Do you see error page . If the page stays on same screen , do you see any exception on server.                                                                                                                                            if none of the above is happening then try to monitor the request in a tool like fire bug etc to monitor what happens when you submit login form.

Comment: The defult login page informs 2 things: "Your login attempt was not successful, try again." "Reason: null". The Spring-Security debug is activated, but NO ERRORS are shown. The system always return a null user for the login attempt. (if it matters, when using static users defined in the XML, it all works).

Comment: This is how I will debug this , monitor the request and response header on login request and see how it differs from when it actually works when you visit second time . You can use firebug in forefox or chrome to see the request and response headers . There must be some difference in the way it is invoked first time and second time.

Comment: I found out where the problem is: @Inject. Whenever I try to inject any bean in my custom UserDetailService, it does not get called by Spring anymore. Now I don't know how to fix this.